# Can Power Automate produce a one time use password that can be used to access an external website?

Tags: power-automate, totp, microsoft-forms

I want to gate-keep a website based on the results of a screening survey (i.e. using Microsoft Forms) which would provide a randomized, one-time use password to a qualifying participant. That participant would receive their password and a link to the website via email. Within a limited time frame that participant may click the website link, receive a prompt to provide the password and then be allowed to access the website.

Is there a  way within power automate to integrate a 2fa or time limited one-time use password system to distribute passwords?

I have conducted a few Google searches and looked into the capabilities of common authenticator systems like Microsoft/Google Authenticator but I don't want my participants to have to install an app or do any other set up than receive an email with the generated code.

Comment: Does it really have to be an additional password tho? I think providing a link that contains the password as a parameter would be more straightforward. Since it's a URL parameter, you can just put whatever you want (just a random GUID if you want it to be one-time, plus expiry time if you need it too) and encrypt it.

Comment: That is interesting. Does Power Automate have the ability to produce URLs with password parameters like that? Would the website need something to recognize and verify the unique password?
Apologies if my questions might seem basic I am just trying to wrap my head around how that would work and if I understand it correctly. Thank you!